# Can't list azure appservices (spring boot apps) in a subscription using Azure Management Libraries for Java

Tags: java, azure, spring-boot, azure-web-app-service, azure-management-api

I'm trying to list my deployed spring boot application in appservices in one of my azure subscription using azure management libraries for java but not able to do so.

Everything works fine from azure cli.

`azure java sdk version 1.18.0 (latest)`
`jdk version 1.8.0_172`

build.gradle

```
dependencies {
    compile group: 'com.microsoft.azure', name: 'azure', version: '1.18.0'
    compile group: 'ch.qos.logback', name: 'logback-classic', version: '1.2.3'
    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.12'
}
```

snippets

```
try {
    Azure azure = Azure
                   .configure()
                   .authenticate(applicationTokenCredentials)
                   .withDefaultSubscription();

            listWebApps(azure);
            listWebAppsUsingAppServicePlan(azure);

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

private static void listWebAppsUsingAppServicePlan(Azure azure){
    PagedList<WebApp> webAppPagedList = azure.appServices().webApps().list();
    System.out.printf("There are %d web apps when searched via azure.appServices().webApps()\n", webAppPagedList.size());
    for (WebApp app : webAppPagedList) {
        System.out.printf("App: %s, Deployment slots: %d", app.name(), app.deploymentSlots().list().size());
    }

}

private static void listWebApps(Azure azure){
    PagedList<WebApp> webAppPagedList = azure.webApps().list();
    System.out.printf("There are %d web apps when searched via azure.webApps()\n", webAppPagedList.size());
    for (WebApp app : webAppPagedList) {
        System.out.printf("App: %s, Deployment slots: %d", app.name(), app.deploymentSlots().list().size());
    }
}
```

Output

`There are 0 web apps when searched via azure.webApps()
There are 0 web apps when searched via azure.appServices().webApps()`

Am I missing something or if there are some prerequisites let me know.

Thanks a ton times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

somehow `azure.webApps().list()` approach was returning an empty list but switching to
`azure.webapps.listAsync()` solved my problem.

**The new Snippet**

```
    azure.webApps().listAsync()
            .subscribe(webApp -> {
                int capacity = webApp.manager().appServicePlans().getById(webApp.appServicePlanId()).capacity();
                System.out.println(webApp.name() + ": " + capacity + (capacity == 1 ? " instance" : " instances"));
            });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I test the code , but not gradle, mine is maven. And I used `az ad sp create-for-rbac --sdk-auth > my.azureauth` to get the `my.azureauth` file , then get the `clientID`,`clientScrect`,`SunscribtionID` and `tenantID`. Here is my result, it works well.

[image]

And here is my code.

```
import com.microsoft.azure.AzureEnvironment;
import com.microsoft.azure.PagedList;
import com.microsoft.azure.credentials.ApplicationTokenCredentials;
import com.microsoft.azure.management.Azure;
import com.microsoft.azure.management.appservice.WebApp;


public class App 
{
public static void main( String[] args )
{

    String client="*******";
    String tenant="*******";
    String key="********";
    String subscriptionId="********";
    ApplicationTokenCredentials credentials = new ApplicationTokenCredentials(
            client, tenant, key, AzureEnvironment.AZURE);
    Azure azure = Azure.authenticate(credentials).withSubscription(subscriptionId);

    System.out.println("asd");
    listWebApps(azure);
    System.out.println("asd");
    listWebAppsUsingAppServicePlan(azure);
}



private static void listWebAppsUsingAppServicePlan(Azure azure){
    PagedList<WebApp> webAppPagedList = azure.appServices().webApps().list();
    System.out.printf("There are %d web apps when searched via azure.appServices().webApps()\n", webAppPagedList.size());
    for (WebApp app : webAppPagedList) {
        System.out.printf("App: %s, Deployment slots: %d", app.name(), app.deploymentSlots().list().size());
    }

}

private static void listWebApps(Azure azure){
    PagedList<WebApp> webAppPagedList = azure.webApps().list();
    System.out.printf("There are %d web apps when searched via azure.webApps()\n", webAppPagedList.size());
    for (WebApp app : webAppPagedList) {
        System.out.printf("App: %s, Deployment slots: %d", app.name(), app.deploymentSlots().list().size());
    }
}

}
```

**Note: it will cost a lot of time while authenticate and run the methods to get the web lists.**
If you still have other questions, please let me know.

Comment: thanks for anwer but before posting the I tried with Credentials file, Cli Authentication but nothing was working.

Comment: Sorry for that.